# How can I read a website as a different IP address?

Tags: screen-scraping, nokogiri, open-uri

I am using Nokogiri to screen scrape a few websites.
My website is hosted on US servers, and so when it fetches the website, the website responses as if the user was a US user. I need the website to responds as if I was an Australian user, even though the server is located in the US.
When running locally it works fine because locally it responds as if it was Australian.

How can I read the site using Nokogiri as if I was from another country?

Comment: I think you'd have to spoof your IP address. I don't think `open_uri` can do this. You'll have to do it on a lower level. Or you could go through a proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run your requests through a proxy in Australia.

This doesn't have anything to do with Nokogiri - it applies no matter how you're trying to scrape a page. HTTP travels over TCP, which is a bi-directional protocol so you can't spoof its IP address. If you tried to spoof the IP address of a TCP packet, you would never get your response back.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure [Tor](http://torproject.org) to always use exit nodes [from a specific country](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/01/29/configure-tor-to-use-a-specific-country-as-an-exit-node/). Please, however, do not use this method if this will put the Tor network under some serious strain (i.e. fetching the pages continually); in this case please consider buying an (Austrlia-based) annonimizing service (or simply a proxy).